# Error: cannot define 'enum class std::align_val_t' in different module

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

I am a C ++ beginner and am looking to create a module. I have followed several guides and would like to test modules with classes. When I try to run the first module via `g++-11 -c -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts func.cxx` i get the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/bits/stl_iterator.h:82,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/bits/stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/string:40,
                 from func.cxx:2:
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/new:89:27: error: cannot define 'enum class std::align_val_t' in different module
   89 |   enum class align_val_t: size_t {};
      |                           ^~~~~~
<built-in>: note: declared here
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/new:89: confused by earlier errors, bailing out
```

Below are the files, thanks in advance.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
import airline_ticket;


int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

func.cxx

```
export module airline_ticket;
#include <string>

export class AirlineTicket
{

public:

AirlineTicket();
~AirlineTicket();

double calculatePriceInDollars(); std::string getPassengerName();

void setPassengerName(std::string name);

int getNumberOfMiles();
void setNumberOfMiles(int miles);

bool hasEliteSuperRewardsStatus();
void setHasEliteSuperRewardsStatus(bool status);

private:
std::string m_passengerName;
int m_numberOfMiles;
bool m_hasEliteSuperRewardsStatus;

};
```

func_impl.cxx

```
module airline_ticket;

AirlineTicket::AirlineTicket()
{
// Initialize data members.
m_passengerName = "Unknown Passenger";
m_numberOfMiles = 0;
m_hasEliteSuperRewardsStatus = false;
}
```

Comment: Note, modules is a very new feature that isn't properly supported by compilers and builds tools yet. Even experts are struggling with them. So maybe wait a year or so with this topic when you're a beginner.

Comment: @JHBonarius it was just that, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the include directive in func.cxx needs to be in the global module fragment area. Else you'll get redefinitions.

I.e.

```
module;
#include <string>
export module .....
...
```

Comment: Or `import<string>;` *after* the `export module`.

Comment: @DavisHerring good suggestion, but doesn't (always?) work out of the box as of yet. You need to build the imported modules first.

Comment: The standard says that works; how to get any one implementation to accept it would be a reasonable (separate) question.